# Workbench does not perform filter for LongText Area field

Tags: query, workbench

In previous release, the possibility to filter by Old value/New Value for history object was introduced.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_filter_old_value_new_value.htm

However, when running a query with Workbench *I login with V 43.0, I get the error:

[image]

Is the Workbench query different than what the report builder is using?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidently I was doing something similar a few days a go, I don't believe it's possible to filter on LongText Area fields in a SOQL or SOSL.

There are a few work arounds such as post processing checks and using copy the first x characters to a Text field which you can filter on (the last option wont be possible in history objects).

[Reports allow this though but it is character restricted](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212391&type=1)

Comment: Thank you for this. But my use case is different. If I use the same search via the report builder, I get answers to the report. But this is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt even Salesforce actually uses SOQL inside the reporting engine. If you want to run a SOQL then you will have to create a formula field using the LEFT function and can filter on that partial text from the long-text area field.